# How to show git log with commit numbers?

Tags: git, git-log

I found an [example on how to delete a commit](https://www.clock.co.uk/insight/deleting-a-git-commit) but it includes git log in the following format

```
Number  Hash    Commit Message  Author
1   2c6a45b (HEAD) Adding public method to access protected method  Tom
2   ae45fab Updates to database interface   Contractor 1
3   77b9b82 Improving database interface    Contractor 2
4   3c9093c Merged develop branch into master   Tom
5   b3d92c5 Adding new Event CMS Module Paul
6   7feddbb Adding CMS class and files  Tom
7   a809379 Adding project to Git   Tom
```

When I issue the `git log` command I'm getting log in another format and without the numbers (which are required by the task).

How to get `git log` with numbers?

Comment: Sounds weird. Might be worth posting the output that you _do_ get with git log. Also what version of git and what os you're using might help.  Be aware that the hash is quite long (like `327bebf545a6024c4e67ecd034cdc1f64a02ce15`) but in many situations you only need the first 8 characters ( `327bebf5` )

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could combine the [`nl`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nl) command with `git log --oneline` to enumerate output lines. It's far from ideal but if you are just looking for the line numbers:

```
$ git log --oneline | nl
 1  91236f3 Message
 2  a611069 Message
 3  f2813e7 Message
 4  01b59e4 Message
 5  2343455 Message
```

Comment: Or if you want to count from first to current: `git log --oneline | tac | nl | tac`